# Use gradient color with custom MaterialShapeDrawable Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, material-components-android

I need custom shape for something like voucher/ticket and i also need drop shadow.

At first, i tried create custom view and draw using Canvas. But i dont know how to achieve the same level drop shadow of CardView.

Then, i decided to do custom `MaterialShapeDrawable` and i managed to do the custom shape with `EdgeTreatment`. And now, i want to change background color using gradient color. How can i do that?

I expect something like pass my own LinearGradient to the paint shader when using custom view. Is it possible to achieve same flexibility to that? Or at least set start/end color and the gradient angle.